# Netcore 2.2 Localized Routing - Route values for default culture always ignored

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-localization

Successfully using the project laid out at [Localized routing using ASP.NET Core MVC 2](https://saaratrix.blogspot.com/2017/12/localized-routing-aspnet-core-mvc-2.html).  The project is developed to display the Default language using just the controller/Action and Localized Routes for the alternate languages.

My Controller

```
[LocalizationRoute("en", "Portal/Dashboard")]
[LocalizationRoute("fr", "Portail/tableau-de-bord")]
[LocalizationRoute("es", "Portal/Tablero")]
public class DashboardController : PortalBaseController
{
    private const string Title = "Dashboard";

    [LocalizationRoute("en", "Dashboardv1")]
    [LocalizationRoute("fr", "tableau-de-bordv1")]
    [LocalizationRoute("es", "Tablerov1")]
    public IActionResult Dashboardver1()
```

In my SignIn controller I wish to create a localised RedirectUrl...the below code provides a fully localized route for the the french and spanish but the default route is always just controller/action.  If I manually type in the english, fully localized route, the page loads but the code below always returns just a regular path.

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;

var redirectUrl = LocalizationRouteDataHandler.GetUrl("Dashboard", "Dashboardver1", culture).Url;
//should be "en/portal/Dashboard/Dashboardv1"
//currently resolves to "Dashboard/Dashboardver1"
```

Suggestions as ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that In `LocalizationRouteDataHandler.AddControllerRouteData` ,code `ControllerRoutes[controllerKey].Names.TryAdd(culture, route);` adds culture="en" and route="Dashboard" first to the Dictionary of Controller Name and then when it tries to add the condition culture="en" and route="en/Portal/Dashboard",it fails since the "en" key has added.

A workaround is that you could remove the unnecessary key and add the new key.

LocalizationRouteDataHandler.cs

```
public static void AddControllerRouteData(string controller, string culture, string route)
    {
        if (controller == "Dashboard")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }
        string controllerKey = controller.ToLower();

        // If the controller doesn't exist, create it!            
        if (!ControllerRoutes.ContainsKey(controllerKey))
        {                
            ControllerRoutes.TryAdd(controllerKey, new CultureControllerRouteData());
        }
        // key removed
        if (culture=="en" && ControllerRoutes[controllerKey].Names.Remove("en"))
        {
            ControllerRoutes[controllerKey].Names.TryAdd(culture, route);

        }
        // dictionary doesn't contain the key
        else
        {
            ControllerRoutes[controllerKey].Names.TryAdd(culture, route);

        }

    }
```

When I test with

```
var redirectUrl = LocalizationRouteDataHandler.GetUrl("Dashboard", "Dashboardver1", "en").Url;
```

It returns `/en/Portal/Dashboard/Dashboardver1`